# Model does not appear to load - naming issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the process of upgrading from Codeigniter 2.2 to 3.1 we renamed all of the models.  Now they are not loading unless I remake them with another name.

Looking at numerous other articles common issues are failing to load the model or typos in the names.  I am not seeing either of these to be the case.  There are several models who all have this issue, but a fix I found which is not ideal is making a new model with a new name. The first example is a model called PrpmsModel  I can take everything in this file and make a new model called FooModel.php and just change the class name in the file to also be FooModel and then when I load it and make a call it works.

```
<?php
/**
 * PRPMS - Model
**/
if (! defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class PrpmsModel extends MY_Model
{
```

I took out the tail end but just to see top definition.

```
$this->load->model('PrpmsModel');
$employee = $this->PrpmsModel->fetchPRPMSbyEmployeeId(1, 1);
```

This does not work above.

```
<?php
/**
 * Foo - Model
**/
if (! defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class FooModel extends MY_Model
{
```

Copied all of PrpmsModel.php into FooModel.php

```
$this->load->model('FooModel');
$employee = $this->FooModel->fetchPRPMSbyEmployeeId(1, 1);
```

This above does work.
The model used to be prpmsModel, so I just changed the case.  The file name was also changed to match the PrpmsModel casing.

Comment: Follow codeigniter naming guidelines. Class name with first letter uppercase and rest lower case like: `class Foo_model`. Then name the file `foo_model.php`.

Comment: This did not change anything.  As I mentioned it works with FooModel, so not sure if the naming conventions are good practice or some underlying requirement.  Seems to be the former.

Comment: it is an underlying requirement in codeigniter. you can look in the core files to see this is the case as to how ci loads classes. also there was a typo, should be `Foo_model.php` with `class Foo_model extends CI_Controller`. this is documented: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming. if after making those changes, and assuring those changes are correct, you still can't load the class, then please update your question with an image of your dir tree as well as the new class declarations/names.

Answer (score 0):

Naming conventions changed between CI 2.x and CI 3.x and are outlined in the 2.x->3.0 migration guide available [HERE](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html)

with specific regard to models, keep in mind that in CI 3:

- File names should always be capitalized on the first character only (`sales_model.php` is NOT OK, neither is `SALES_MODEL.php` nor `Sales_Model.php`. `Sales_model.php` IS OK)
- The model's class name must match the file name (using the previous example, your Class declaration should be `Class Sales_model extends CI_Model { }`
- The model should be loaded in your controller using an all-lowercase name (so `$this->load->model('sales_model');` IS OK, while `$this->load->model('Sales_model');`, `$this->load->model('Sales_Model');` or `$this->load->model('SALES_MODEL');` are not)

Make sure everything in your migrated codebase adheres to the above conventions and you should be fine. If not, some more code (and also error/debug logs) would be needed to help you debug.

Since you'll already be reviewing the 2.x->3.0 migration guide, take the time to review the whole document. A lot changed from 2.x to 3.x, so it definitely wouldn't hurt to make sure everything conforms to 3.x standards